TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') , i integrate gpt-3.5-turbo with a chat web app in my backend file and this error came
I am building a project where I'm using chat engine and Open AI's gpt-3.5. Basically this is web based chat application where you can chat with normal user and there will be a option called chat with AI . After using chatgpt-3.5-turbo , I got to know that , the credit points for tokens are not enough to experiment. So I use reverse proxy method to use it for free. Below I'm sharing my code =>
import express from "express";
import axios from "axios";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { openai } from "../index.js";

dotenv.config();
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/text", async(req,res) => {
    try {
        const { text,activeChatId } =  req.body;
        console.log(" ~ router.post ~ req.body:", req.body)
        const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
            model:"gpt-3.5-turbo" ,
            prompt: text,
            temperature: 0.7,
            max_tokens: 2048,
            top_p: 1,
            frequency_penalty: 0.5,
            presence_penalty: 0,
            stream: true,
        });

        await axios.post(
            `https://api.openai.com/chats/${activeChatId}/messages/`,
            { text: response.choices[0].message.content },
            
            {
                headers: {
                              "Project-ID": process.env.PROJECT_ID,
                              "User-Name": process.env.BOT_USER_NAME,
                              "User-Secret": process.env.BOT_USER_SECRET,
            }
        }
        );
      

        res.status(200).json({ text: response.choices[0].message.content })
  
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("1st error",error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message })
    }
})
export default router;

my index.js file =>
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
import OpenAI from "openai";
import openAiRoutes from "./routes/openai.js";
/*CONFIGURATION*/
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin"}))
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit:"30mb", extended:"true" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit:"30mb", extended: "true" }));
app.use(cors());

// OPENAI CONFIGURATION
export const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPEN_API_KEY,
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3040/v1",
  });
app.use("/openai",openAiRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`It is running on Port: ${PORT}`);
});


When i try to run this code, it's giving me this error =>
::1 - - [26/May/2024:20:00:08 +0000] "OPTIONS /openai/text HTTP/1.1" 204 0
 ~ router.post ~ req.body: {
  attachments: [],
  created: '2024-05-26 20:00:08.331885+00:00',
  sender_username: 'testid',
  text: 'hi',
  activeChatId: 252894
}
1st error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at file:///D:/Web%20D/Chat-app/server/routes/openai.js:26:37
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
::1 - - [26/May/2024:20:00:10 +0000] "POST /openai/text HTTP/1.1" 500 61


Can anybody give me any solution for this problem.

Don't use "stream: true" if you don't really use a stream
